# how to display pic with slider from json source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON file which contains the address of pics, I used get JSON for connect to JSON file, and also I am using a plugin called"lightslider" to show the pictures, my problem is when I run the HTML noting show but after refreshing the page it shows. and other problem is it is work only on fire fox. and also in server not working on server. please give me some easy and possible way to show my pic on slider from JSON file which is works on all browser. thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>link3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="lightslider.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lightslider.js"></script> 
    <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#image-gallery').lightSlider({
                item:1,
                speed:500,
                auto:true,
                loop:true,
                pause: 3000,
                pauseOnHover:true,
                thumbItem:9,
                slideMargin: 0,
                autoWidth:true,
                onSliderLoad: function() {
                    $('#image-gallery').removeClass('cS-hidden');
                }  
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function(){

    $.getJSON('slides.json', function(data) {
    $("h2").html(data[0].title);
            $.each(data, function (i, f) {
                if(i>0){
                    $("#image-gallery").append("<li><img src=" + f.content + "/></li>");
                }
            });
       });
    });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <h2 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bolder;">
        </h2>
        <div class="clearfix container" style="max-width:900px;" >
            <ul id="image-gallery" class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding your problem on JavaScript only working after refreshing try to wrap your code in `window.onload = function(){}` so that your code is loaded after DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: actually i am looking for some better way to show my image on JSON into html. do you have an idea or any suggested plugins

Comment: are you testing your solution on double clicking a html file such as `file:///Users/../index.html` or on a web server? inspect your web console on chrome and see if there are any errors and update your question if any.